# Dagger used in text as a reference

Tags: typesetting, cross-reference, footnotes

Should a dagger (obelisk) come before or after its reference word? 
This symbol looks like a cross, sometimes refered to as a printer's mark
(†) used esp. for references.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a situation that you're referencing? I'm not quite sure if I am understanding you

Comment: †Microvasive (there is an arrow pointing to the left at the device it is referring to, the following text is what prints further down on the label - just like an asterisk reference.                                                                                                                    † MICROVASIVE is a Registered Trademark of Boston Scientific Corporation.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely after, just like a regular asterisk when placed in the main body of text. Then, before the referenced text when used in the footnote.

It is actually just another different looking asterisk, for when you need to highlight multiple references, so the same logic applies.

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: is this still true for RTL languages? I wouldn't think so

Comment: No idea, probably not, as LTR logic doesn't really work in RTL. Then again this is likely a LTR question, otherwise the OP would have mentioned this.